# Finding Length of Circlular Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, list, doubly-linked-list

I am having some trouble with counting the elements of my circular doubly linked list

here is the node class:

```
public class Node {
  private Node previous, next;
  private Object data;

  public Node(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public Node() {

  }

  public Node(Object data, Node previous, Node next) {
    this.previous = previous;
    this.next = next;
    this.data = data;
  }

  public Node getPrevious() {
    return previous;
  }

  public void setPrevious(Node previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
  }

  public Node getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public Object getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

and here is where I have my methods for my doubly linked list

```
public class DList {

  private Node base;

  public DList() {

  }

  /**
   * Return the number of elements in the list.
   */
  public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    if (base == null)
        return count;
    else {
        Node temp = base;
        do {
            temp = temp.getNext();
            count++;
        } while (temp != base);
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

when testing, the result should be 5, but my function isn't counting anything.

Comment: Unless you have a circular list as well, your loop condition is wrong. It should probably be `while (temp != null)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, it is a circular list. My bad :(

Answer (score 0):

The other answer won't quite work, in the case where base is the only element. It should be a while, like:

```
public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    if (base.getNext() == base)
        return count;
    else {
        Node temp = base.getNext();
        while (temp != base) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Your code was assuming that you were using a circular doubly-linked list, and this assumes a null-terminated list. Which were you going for?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it is a circular list

Comment: Thanks for the help! Im getting a null pointer exception and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I think your previous code was assuming that you were using a circular doubly-linked list, and alpert's answer provides count for a non-circularly linked list

If you want to create a circular doubly-linked list try the following:
`setNext(Node node)` you should set `node.previous = this;`

`setPrevious(Node node)` you should  set `node.next = this;`

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking for `temp != null`, but really your code should be a lot simpler.

Just do this:

```
public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    for (Node node = base; node != null; node = node.getNext())
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Less code means less bugs and it's easier to read and understand.